# Missing records after Marketing Cloud FTP Export in my local file

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, automationstudio, data-export, email-studio

Today I did an Enhanced FTP export from a Data Extension that was holding 8,498,752 records with 166 MB.
In the Enhanced FTP directory, a file for it was generated with the size of 203,632 KB.
I transferred it to my local folder & when I opened it, I got to see only 1,046,574 records & the rest weren't there.
I tried exporting a couple of times compressing the file but nothing helped me. I couldn't figure out the solution.
Can someone help me understand why this is happening?
Is there a size restriction for export?
What steps I need to take to export all of the records?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

As long as the export was executed correctly (if there is a file - yes), the file will contain all the records the Data Extension has. You can verify that by importing the exact same file back to another DE and receiving an email notification with the import results.

As for the opening of large files, there is a [limitation of Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3) to only open up to 1 048 576 rows by 16 384 columns. To avoid that you would need either to split the file into smaller ones or use some dedicated application for opening large .csv files (e.g. [Gigasheet](https://www.gigasheet.co/))

Comment: Thanks for your response! It helped me understand where I was stuck.